# post method in Python

Tags: python, post

I want to write a script in Python that would connect and post some data to several web-servers automatically.
Please write how to post and submit data for example to google. Just can't understand how to do it from Python documentation. Thank You.

Comment: Step 1: Search.  This is a well-asked question.  Numerous answers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python URLLib / URLLib2 POST](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3238925/python-urllib-urllib2-post)

Comment: Please research yourself before asking - SO is not about please-research-in-SO-for-me

Answer (score 3):

Check the documentation on the urllib2 module and check out this [urllib2 the missing manual](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/urllib2.shtml). It's all there.

Answer (score 0):

If you are open for packages outside standard library, then [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/#examples) is a good option for such tasks.