# VCloud Director Org user authentication for RestAPI in python

Tags: python, authentication, vmware, vcloud-director-rest-api

I have VMware setup for testing. I create one user abc/abc123 to access the Org url "http://localhost/cloud/org/MyOrg". I want to access the RestAPI of the VCloud. I tried with **RestClient** plugin in **firefox**. Its working fine.

Now I tried with python code.

```
url = 'https://localhost/api/sessions/'
req = urllib2.Request(url)
base64string = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % ('abc@MyOrg', 'abc123'))[:-1]
authheader =  "Basic %s" % base64string
req.add_header("Authorization", authheader)
req.add_header("Accept", 'application/*+xml;version=1.5')

f = urllib2.urlopen(req)
data = f.read()
print(data)
```

This is the code i get from stackoverflow. But for my example its give "urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden" Error.

I also tried HTTP authentication for the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After doing some googling I found the solution from the post https://stackoverflow.com/a/6348729/243031. I change the code for my usability. I am posting the answer because if some one has same error then he will get the answer directly.

My change code is:

```
import urllib2
import base64

# make a string with the request type in it:
method = "POST"
# create a handler. you can specify different handlers here (file uploads etc)
# but we go for the default
handler = urllib2.HTTPSHandler()
# create an openerdirector instance
opener = urllib2.build_opener(handler)
# build a request
url = 'https://localhost/api/sessions'
request = urllib2.Request(url)
# add any other information you want
base64string = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % ('abc@MyOrg', 'abc123'))[:-1]
authheader =  "Basic %s" % base64string
request.add_header("Authorization", authheader)
request.add_header("Accept",'application/*+xml;version=1.5')

# overload the get method function with a small anonymous function...
request.get_method = lambda: method
# try it; don't forget to catch the result
try:
    connection = opener.open(request)
except urllib2.HTTPError,e:
    connection = e

# check. Substitute with appropriate HTTP code.
if connection.code == 200:
    data = connection.read()
    print "Data :", data
else:
    print "ERRROR", connection.code
```

Hope this will help some one who want to send **POST** request without the data.