# How do I send a POST request to the page after it has been opened using Python?

Tags: python, post, python-2.7, web-scraping, httprequest

I want to send a POST request to the page after opening it using Python (using `urllib2.urlopen`). Webpage is http://wireless.walmart.com/content/shop-plans/?r=wm

Code which I am using right now is:

```
url = 'http://wireless.walmart.com/content/shop-plans/?r=wm'
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1;Trident/5.0)'   
values = {'carrierID':'68',
'conditionToType':'1',
'cssPrepend':'wm20',
'partnerID':'36575'}
headers = { 'User-Agent' : user_agent }
data = urllib.urlencode(values)
req = urllib2.Request(url, data, headers)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
page = response.read()
walmart = open('Walmart_ContractPlans_ATT.html','wb')
walmart.write(page)
```

This is giving me page which opens by default, after inspecting the page using Firebug I came to know that `carrierID:68` is sent when I click on the button which sends this POST request.

I want to simulate this browser behaviour.

Please help me in resolving this.

Comment: You might check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348499/making-a-post-call-instead-of-get-using-urllib2?lq=1

Comment: "when I click on the button which sends this POST request", wchih button are you referring to?

Comment: @elyase `Sprint` button on the page

Comment: So do you want to extract Plans for a specific carrier or do you want to extract the carrier's IDs from the main page?

Comment: plans for a specific carrier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For webscraping I prefer to use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart.html) and [pyquery](http://pythonhosted.org/pyquery/). First you download the data:

```
import requests
from pyquery import PyQuery as pq

url = 'http://wireless.walmart.com/content/getRatePlanInfo'
payload = {'carrierID':68, 'conditionToType':1, 'cssPrepend':'wm20'}
r = requests.post(url, data=payload)
d = pq(r.text)
```

After this you proceed to parse the elements, for example to extract all plans:

```
plans = []
plans_selector = '.wm20_planspage_planDetails_sub_detailsDiv_ul_li'
plans = d(plans_selector).each(lambda i, n: plans.append(pq(n).text()))
```

Result:

```
 ['Basic 200',
 'Simply Everything',
 'Everything Data 900',
 'Everything Data 450',
 'Talk 450',
 ...
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, couldn't accept earlier because of the weekend.

Comment: How did you get the result? When I am printing `plans` I am getting this sort of o/p `[<li.wm20_planspage_planDetails_sub_detailsDiv_ul_li>, <li.wm20_planspage_planDetails_sub_detailsDiv_ul_li>, `

Comment: add this `from __future__ import print_function`, but honestly I am not sure why that is needed. I will look into it when I have some time.

Comment: Ok I updated my answer, I changed `n.text` to `pq(n).text()`, it should work now without the `print_function` thing.

Comment: How did you find this link `http://wireless.walmart.com/content/getRatePlanInfo` as the link I gave in the question was different.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend looking at a browser emulator like [mechanize](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mechanize/), rather than trying to do this with raw HTTP requests.

Comment: I only know basic form filling using Mechanize, when I opened this page using it and checked for br.forms() I couldn't find any which can be filled and submitted. Can we send POST request also using Mechanize? If yes, then how?