# POST method in Python: errno 104

Tags: python, http-post, python-requests, urllib

I am trying to query a website in Python. I need to use a POST method (according to what is happening in my browser when I monitor it with the developer tools).

If I query the website with cURL, it works well:

```
curl -i --data "param1=var1&param2=var2" http://www.test.com
```

I get this header:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 26 Sep 2017 08:46:18 GMT
Server: Apache/1.3.33 (Unix) mod_gzip/1.3.26.1a mod_fastcgi/2.4.2 PHP/4.3.11
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html
```

But when I do it in Python 3, I get an error 104.

Here is what I tried so far. First, with `urllib` (getting inspiration from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348499/making-a-post-call-instead-of-get-using-urllib2) to manage to use a POST method instead of GET):

```
import re
from urllib import request as ur

# URL to handle request                                                                                      
url = "http://www.test.com"
data = "param1=var1&param2=var2"

# Build a request dictionary
preq = [re.findall("[^=]+", i) for i in re.findall("[^\&]+", data)]
dreq = {i[0]: i[1] if len(i) == 2 else "" for i in preq}

# Initiate request & add method
ureq = ur.Request(url)                                                                                     
ureq.get_method = lambda: "POST"                                                                           
# Send request                                                                                             
req = ur.urlopen(ureq, data=str(dreq).encode())
```

I did basically the same with `requests`:

```
import re
import requests

# URL to handle request                                                                                      
url = "http://www.test.com"
data = "param1=var1&param2=var2"

# Build a request dictionary
preq = [re.findall("[^=]+", i) for i in re.findall("[^\&]+", data)]
dreq = {i[0]: i[1] if len(i) == 2 else "" for i in preq}

# Initiate request & add method
req = requests.post(url, data=dreq)
```

In both cases, I get a HTTP 104 error:

```
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

That I don't understand since the same request is working with cURL. I guess I misunderstood something with Python request but so far I'm stuck. Any hint would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just figured out I did not pass data in the right format. I thought it needed to be store in a `dict`; that is not the case and it is therefore much more simple that what I tried previously.

With `urllib`:

```
req = ur.urlopen(ureq, data=str(data).encode())
```

With `requests`:

```
req = requests.post(url, data=data)
```