# HTTP POST & 302 redirect in Python

Tags: python, redirect, post

I am trying to query a server with a `POST` method in Python.

```
import requests

url  = "https://www.test.com/service"
data = {"param": "value"}

req = requests.post(url, data).content
```

When I look at `req`, it clearly doesn't take into account the data I posted.

If I check the header with cURL:

```
curl -ik -X POST -d "param=value" https://www.test.com/service
```

I get the following `HTTP 302`:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Déplacé Temporairement
Date: Fri, 06 Oct 2017 16:42:36 GMT
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
Location: https://www.test.com/redirect
Content-Language: fr-FR
Content-Length: 0
Via: 1.1 www.test.com
```

So if I understand well, I am redirected to `Location` which is `https://www.test.com/redirect`. This address can only be query with a `GET` method; if I try with a `POST`, I get a `HTTP 500` error.

What I understand thus is that I am `POST`ing a request with parameters and I am redirected to another page and the request becomes a `GET`, querying `Location`. I don't understand then what happens to my parameters: in my browser, I get an answer that takes into account the parameters sent, when I query it by hand they seem to be "lost" since I just get kind of an empty version of `https://www.test.com/redirect`.

What do I miss? My understanding of requests is pretty shallow so I'm sure I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Correct syntax to use `requests.post`.  [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#make-a-request)

```
import requests

url  = "https://www.test.com/service"
data = {"param":"value"}

req = requests.post(url, data).content
```

Comment: I edited my question, it was an unfortunate typo. I doesn't work with the correct syntax, I do have this issue. If I had done this mistake, from [my experience](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46422307/post-method-in-python-errno-104), it should else trigger a `104 error`!