# Submiting Javascript Form and Scrape with Python

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, urllib

I have the following HTML/Javascript code in a website. It basically represents a website with two fields: a) name="N": Field were you mark the "V" letter; b) name="ID" were you input a number with max 8 characters.

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <form name="form" method="post" action="javascript:BuscaR(document.form.N.value, document.form.ID.value)">
<table class="aux">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select name="N" class="form">
            <option value="V">V</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="ID" type="text" class="form"  maxlength="8" size="8" value="ID" onfocus="javascript:clear_textbox3();" onblur="javascript:Valid(document.form.ID);"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" value="Buscar" class="boton"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
</td>
```

I have done webscrapers with BeautifulSoup and urllib before. My idea is to produce a script which inputs and submits these ID numbers (from a huge database), and retrieves the data which the website responds (it returns a HTML).

**However, I can't find where does this form "leads" to. I mean, how do I input? How do I "press" submit in Python?**

On most [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16425031/submiting-form-with-python), we now what is the php URL were submitting the Form leads. So they can change the ID in `php.?N=V,ID=x` and "brute force" different numbers. Yet I cannot find this url in the website. What do I do?

The original website is http://www.cne.gob.ve/web/index.php on the right side it says "Consulte sus Datos. Proceso de validación y exclusión de registros presentados por el partido MUD." and the box presents a search buttom.

Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a simple get request, passing two params:

[image]

So with requests:

```
url = "http://www.cne.gob.ve/web/registro_electoral/firmantes.php"

params = {"nacionalidad":"V",
"cedula":"12345678"}

page = requests.get(url, params=params)
print(page.content)
```

If you pass a correct id you will get a table of data returned, using 12345678 you see a table returned and *Esta Cédula de Identidad no se encuentra en la base de datos de los registros presentados por el partido MUD* as obviously it is not a valid id.

Comment: Oh my god! It's that simple. I can't believe it. Just one question: How did you got the .php page? I used Chrome's source code to get the code I copied but I didn't knew what else to do to find what you did find.

Comment: Open developer tools, hit the network tab, submit a request then check the xhr tab, you will see exactly what happens.

Comment: thank you very much, man. Personally, and on behalf of a lot of countrymates. Sorry for the melodrama

Comment: No worries, it is only simple when you know how!