# Python mongolab REST api

Tags: python, api, rest, mlab

I am trying to access the mongolab REST api through python. Is the correct way to do this via pythons urllib2? I have tried the following:

```
import urllib2

p = urllib2.urlopen("https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/mydb/collections/mycollection?apiKey=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
```

But this gives me an error:

```
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error unknown url type: https>
```

What is the correct way of doing this? After connecting, how do I go on to POST a document to my collection? If someone could post up a code example, I would be very grateful. Thanks all for the help!

EDIT:

I've recompiled python with ssl support. How do I POST insert a document to a collection using mongolab REST API? Here is the code I have atm:

```
import urllib
import urllib2

url = "https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/mydb/collections/mycollection?apiKey=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
data = {"x" : "1"}
request = urllib2.Request(url, data)
p = urllib2.urlopen(request)
```

Now, when I run this, I get the error

```
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 415: Unsupported Media Type
```

How do I insert documents using HTTP POST? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That error is raised if you version of python does not include ssl support. What version are you using? Did you compile it yourself?

That said, when you get a version including ssl, using [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.org/en/v1.1.0/) is a lot easier than urllib2, especially when POSTing data.

Comment: Thanks, I've recompiled Python with ssl. Sticking with urllib2 for the moment though, how do I POST a new document to my collection with mongolab REST API?

Comment: How to post with urllib2: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3238925/python-urllib-urllib2-post