# python SOAP client that uses POST method

Tags: python, soap, soap-client, suds

Tried using suds for having a python SOAP client, but it uses get, not post and my server requires POST. Is there any trick to get suds going, or do you know of a client that supports POST?

```
from suds.client import Client

url = 'file:///myfile.wsdl'
client = Client(url)
client.service.myfunction()
```

Comment: from suds.client import Client
url = 'file:///myfile.wsdl'
client = Client(url)
client.service.myfunction()

Comment: SOAP against a `file` URL? How is that supposed to work? Is this your real code?

Comment: yes, that's my real code. The name url there is not suggestive. It's the location of the wsdl file. I copied it from suds' documentation, where the wsdl file was located on the internet, not in a local file. The documentation is at https://fedorahosted.org/suds/wiki/Documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my problem was I was missing a trailing '/' in the server address. This post has more details [Python URLLib / URLLib2 POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3238925/python-urllib-urllib2-post)