# HTTP POST REQUEST using python

Tags: python, http, post

I've a web server setup in a separate location and I wanted to access it remotely using HTTP POST request. Can someone please guide me how to proceed with it. I need to use Python which runs the HTTP Post request and modifies the contents of the WEB page

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/urllib2.html

Answer (score 1):

Although probably not particularly practical, you could use a socket. A script on the server which receives the POST request would have to modify the desired web pages content upon receipt.

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket()
sock.connect(('server_domainname.com', 80))
sock.sendall(b'POST / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: server_domainname.com:80\r\n\r\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the basic idea is to create a connection, build some headers and data, then go ahead and send that request, get the response from the connection, and then you can then read the response.

```
connection = httplib.HTTPConnection('<yourServerAddress>:<port>')
headers = ... # Some JSON
data = ... # Some data
connection.request('POST', 'resource/name/goes/here', data, headers)
response = connection.getresponse()
# Let's print what we get back
print response.read()
```

Please see: [Python URLLib / URLLib2 POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3238925/python-urllib-urllib2-post)