# How to optimize python import requests statement

Tags: python, import, python-requests

I have a python application that is fairly large when I use `pyinstaller` to bundle it, so I'm looking for ways to reduce its size. It uses `requests`, but only to make one post request. Is there a way to use a statement like `from requests import ___` and still be able to make this post request? And in general, what's the best way to find documentation on the subsets of functionality that are available for import for a given python library?

Comment: Can't you get rid of requests altogether and use [urllib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3238925/python-urllib-urllib2-post) instead?

Comment: Sure I could, but I'd like to know how `requests` can be split up if at all. And I have the same question regarding `wxPython`.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to Question 1: You can certainly do something like this since it's only `post` that you need:

```py
from requests import post
```

Be warned though that you'll need to re-factor your code to replace all instances where you called `requests.post()`

Answer to Question 2: Normally library developers provide API documentation. The standard libraries of course have their own: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/index.html. Your miles may definitely vary depending on the library you're using. `requests` in particular has the documentation for `post` as a pydoc:
[image]